# Twig and Codeigniter error : Call to a member function flashdata() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig, codeigniter-3

I am trying to add a codeigniter function `$this->session->flashdata()` at twig library. But I am getting below error:

```
Type: Error
Message: Call to a member function flashdata() on null
```

My code at twig library is:

```
$this->twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('flash_data', function($data){return $this->session->flashdata($data);}));
```

and at my twig file I am calling like this:    `{{ flash_data('login_error') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('flash_data', function($data){

$obj =& get_instance();

return $obj->session->flashdata($data);

}));
```